# What's the impact of changing a certificate's friendly name?

Tags: windows, certificate, mmc

Scenario

My Nagios isn't showing the name of some certificates about to expire. It only shows the date for some of them.
But I'm afraid that I adding a friendly name it would change the certificate in a way that it could stop working.

Question

What's the impact of changing a certificate's friendly name on a Windows Server through the MMC utility? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually add a friendly name to the certificate without problems in this case.

Most software uses the thumbprint to identify the certificate which it should use.

Only very few programs i know use the friendly name instead.

But since your friendly name is currently empty, this should not be the case here and you are good to go. Changing the friendly name does not change the thumbprint.

Comment: Thanks, @japi. I added the friendly name and everything seems to be working.